# parse package name and version number using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing

I have strings where I have to parse a name and a version number as separate fields. Version number may include alphabets as well.

Example Strings:

```
AntivirusOwner10.5.6.R01.Vr561
Antivirus2010Owner10.5.6.R01.Vr561
Antivirus_abc Movbsd 2008 abc r6 10.20.161.17
Antivirus_abc Movbsd .abc 4.5.6.7
Antivirus_abc Movbsd .mnc 4
```

Expected separation:

> ```
> AntivirusOwner                       10.5.6.R01.Vr561
> Antivirus2010Owner                   10.5.6.R01.Vr561
> Antivirus_abc Movbsd 2008 abc r6     10.20.161.1
> Antivirus_abc Movbsd .abc            4.5.6.7
> Antivirus_abc Movbsd .mnc            4
> ```

Comment: if your string is in `$InString`, then this seems to work >>> `$InString -match '^(?<Name>[a-z]+)(?<Version>\d.+)$'` <<< the results are in the `$Matches` automatic variable.

Comment: Need to create two columns(X,Y) where X has its package name and Y has its Version number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example strings, I would say, we assume that the package name ends before there is a number followed by a `.`. A regex for this would look like in this example:

```
$packageDescriptions = "AntivirusOwner10.5.6.R01.Vr561", "Antivirus2010Owner10.5.6.R01.Vr561", "Antivirus_IIS .Net10.12.14.16", "Antivirus_abc Movbsd 2008 abc r6 10.20.161.17", "Antivirus_abc Movbsd .abc 4.5.6.7", "Antivirus_abc Movbsd .mnc 4"
foreach ($packageDescription in $packageDescriptions) {
    if ($packageDescription -imatch "^(.*?)(\d+\.[\w\.]*|\d+)$") {
        Select-Object @{n='PackageName'; e={$Matches[1]}}, @{n='PackageVersion'; e={$Matches[2]}} -InputObject ''
    } else {
        Write-Warning "'$packageDescription' is not covered by this regex!"
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> PackageName                       PackageVersion  
> -----------                       --------------  
> AntivirusOwner                    10.5.6.R01.Vr561
> Antivirus2010Owner                10.5.6.R01.Vr561
> Antivirus_IIS .Net                10.12.14.16     
> Antivirus_abc Movbsd 2008 abc r6  10.20.161.17    
> Antivirus_abc Movbsd .abc         4.5.6.7
> Antivirus_abc Movbsd .mnc         4
> ```

Explanation of the regex `"^(.*?)(\d+\.[\w\.]*|\d+)$"`:

It has two groups encapsulated by `()`. First will be the name. It matches on everything, but in an ungreedy way (see addition of `?`) so that group 2 will take precedence. Group 2  (version) says it has to start with at least one digit followed by a dot followed by alphanumeric characters and dots OR just some pure digits to catch the case where version only consists of `4` (without dots).